# How to properly traverse cells in a Nat Table?

Tags: java, nattable

I have a simple `CustomTextCellEditor` that extends `AbstractCellEditor`

I tried to traverse a cell, if the arrow key is pressed when the cell is either empty or we are at the end of the cell data.

```
textFieldControl.addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener() {

    @Override
    public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent e) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
        case SWT.ARROW_DOWN:                    
            commit(MoveDirectionEnum.DOWN, true);
            break;
        case SWT.ARROW_UP:
            commit(MoveDirectionEnum.UP, true);
            break;
        case SWT.ARROW_LEFT:
            if(textFieldControl.getText().length()==0 || textFieldControl.getCaretPosition() == 0 )
                commit(MoveDirectionEnum.LEFT, true);
            break;
        case SWT.ARROW_RIGHT:
            if(textFieldControl.getText().length()==0 || textFieldControl.getCaretPosition() == textFieldControl.getText().length() )
                commit(MoveDirectionEnum.RIGHT, true);
            break;
        }
    }
});

@Override
public boolean activateOnTraversal(IConfigRegistry configRegistry, List<String> configLabels) {
    return true;
}
```

Thing is, the `activateOnTraversal` is never called, and while yes, when I hit the arrow key at the appropriate time, it changes focus to the desired cell, it does not activate.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Traversal is triggered via **TAB** not the arrow keys. If you use a `KeyListener` instead of a `TraversalListener` it should work.

What you try to achieve is already supported by the `TextCellEditor`. So you could have a look at that implementation to see how it works.

For activating the next editor after traversal you either need to override `AbstractCellEditor#activateOnTraversal()` to return always true or configure the `EditConfigAttributes.ACTIVATE_EDITOR_ON_TRAVERSAL` for `DisplayMode#EDIT` to be true. The same applies to `AbstractCellEditor#openAdjacentEditor()` and `EditConfigAttributes.OPEN_ADJACENT_EDITOR`.

Comment: Thing is, I'm overwriting a bit of the Cell Editor, thus I need a few of the things it does naturally, re-implemented. I've checked the github and the traverse is done with `commit(MoveDirectionEnum.RIGHT)`, just like me, yet it's not happening. Sure it's not on a keyListener, but it still goes to that code, it still gets to the commit, and it still does the commit. It just doesn't activate a cell.

Comment: I updated the answer for the activation of an adjacent editor. That is also already supported by the editor framework in NatTable, but disabled by default.